# How to get all the item filters in ebay python SDK

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

I am working with the python SDK of eBay and I am trying to programatically get all of the item filters. Basically this list (http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/ItemFilterType.html)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to obtain a complete list of *ItemFilterType* values such as *Condition* and *AuhorizedSellerOnly* you may be able to do so by parsing the WSDL available for the Finding API.

The WSDL is available at http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/Finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl The idea is that you can download the file and search for the following element.

```
<xs:simpleType name="ItemFilterType">
```

Within this element you can iterate through the following elements.

```
<xs:enumeration/>
```

The value attribute of each element should be the information that you are looking for.The example below is simplified version of what you can expect in the WSDL.

```
<xs:simpleType name="ItemFilterType">
    <xs:enumeration value="Condition"></xs:enumeration>
    <xs:enumeration value="Currency"></xs:enumeration>
    <xs:enumeration value="EndTimeFrom"></xs:enumeration>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I can easily parse that in python. Thanks :)